# file upload occurs on cancel button click salesforce vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am using this below javascript to check the size of the file before upload happens.

```
<script>
    function getIEFileSize(file){
        var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        filepath = file.value,
        thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
        return thefile.size;
    }

    function checkFileSize()
    {
        var goodSize = true;
        $('input[type=file]').each(function()
        {
            if(typeof this.files[0] !== 'undefined')
            {
                var file = this.files[0],
                size = typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined' ?
                    getIEFileSize(file)
                    :
                    file.fileSize || file.size;

                goodSize = 25000000 > size;
                if(!goodSize)
                {
                    alert(this.files[0].name +' is too large - please choose a file that is 25Mb or less');
                }
                else
                {
                    if (2000000 < size)
                    {
                        goodSize=confirm('The file size is ' + size + 
                            ' bytes - this may take some time. Are you sure you wish to continue');
                    }
                }

                return goodSize;
            }
        });
        return goodSize;
    }

  </script>
```

This is called from a commandbutton -

```
<apex:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="{!saveAll}" onClick="return checkFileSize();"  />

<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"  />
```

When i click the cancel command button. It is showing the upload progress and then redirecting to the previous page.

I don't this upload progress shouyld happen. Can anyone tell what is going wrong.

Regards

Comment: You can try to do immediate="true" on cancel button. That would not send any newly entered data to salesforce

Comment: Still the upload is happening in cancel